# Error message (FailedPrecondition: 400 User location is not supported for the API use.) when using the 51GB Google Colab runtime and Palm API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, palm-api

The Google PaLM API (import google.generativeai as palm) works successfully when I use a 2 CPU colab runtime.

However, when I switch to an 8 CPU, 51 GB colab runtime (via Colab Pro+), I get an error when running a simple PaLM API request.  The error message says:

`FailedPrecondition: 400 User location is not supported for the API use.`

What I tried:

- When I switch back to the 2 CPU Colab runtime, everything works.  It is only when I switch to the high RAM 51GB runtime, where it does not work.
- After I pip install google-generativeai, I do restart the runtime, so that is not the issue, as that works with the 2 CPU Colab runtime.
- Note, some days it does work and some days it seemingly randomly does not.  I want to use the 8 CPU  Colab runtime in order to speed up my colab.

---

Here is a sample colab with the minimal code to reproduce the error: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fm4CZjj_axPssIOkBRi4V6JxX9q1Zt4p?usp=sharing

Note, to run the above colab, you'll need to upload your own PaLM API key.

---

If you have this same issue, you can +1 the bug I created in the Google issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/284912713).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `!curl ipinfo.io` to check where your colab instance is located.
just a quick test 2 of 3 "high ram" instances I created landed in Belgium. Belgium is not in the "allowed regions" list.

Answer (score 2):

Palm api is currently only supported in a limited number of countries [available_regions](https://developers.generativeai.google/available_regions)

Mostly EU isnt supported.

If you are getting "400 User location is not supported for the API use." its because your not in the proper region.

Swaping around Colab does tend to move you to a different server and sometimes it clicks in. Im pretty sure this issue has been fixed.

Comment: Regarding "I'm pretty sure this issue has been fixed" -- I live in Mountain View, California, and still intermittently get this error when running Google Colab.  The most recent error was yesterday.

Comment: I can report it for you, I cant recreate it as I am in an unsupported country so it happens when my VPN is acting up. I normally just switch regions.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by disabling IPV6 for on my server.

1. Run

```
ping generativelanguage.googleapis.com -4
```

To get the IPV4 of the domain name.

2. Edit `/etc/hosts/` Replace the IP address with the one you find in step 1.

```
172.217.2.202 generativelanguage.googleapis.com
```