# Gemini API working in localhost, but not on server

Tags: php, google-gemini

I am calling free Gemini API using PHP. It is working absolutely fine on localhost.

I encountered an issue upon deploying it to a shared hosting server. Irrespective of the location, even when accessed from New York, the system consistently returns an error message:

> {"error":"Gemini API operation failed:
> operation=models/gemini-pro:generateContent, status_code=400,
> response={\n  "error": {\n    "code": 400,\n    "message":
> "User location is not supported for the API use.",\n    "status":
> "FAILED_PRECONDITION"\n  }\n}\n"}

Could you kindly assist me in resolving this issue?

```
php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GeminiAPI\Client;
use GeminiAPI\Enums\MimeType;
use GeminiAPI\Resources\Parts\ImagePart;
use GeminiAPI\Resources\Parts\TextPart;

// Path to the image containing the voucher
$imagePath = "PATH";

// API key for accessing Gemini API
$apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY';
$client = new Client($apiKey);

// Read the image file content and encode it in base64
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($imagePath));

// Prompt to provide context for content generation
$prompt = "MY_PROMPT";

try {
    // Send the image and text to Gemini API for processing
    $response = $client->geminiProVision()->generateContent(
        new TextPart($prompt),
        new ImagePart(MimeType::IMAGE_JPEG, $imageData)
    );

    // Extract the JSON response
    $content = $response->text();

    // Return the JSON data
    echo extractJSON($content);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // If an error occurs, return an error message
    echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}

function extractJSON($string) {
    $pattern = '/\{(.*?)\}/s'; // pattern to match
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches); // perform the match
    if (isset($matches[0])) {
        return $matches[0]; // return the first captured group
    } else {
        return "{}"; // return null if no match found
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is the hosted server located? What does the API consider to be valid locations? (I'd assume it detects this based on IP address? Or is it perhaps related to the location of the account the API is registered to? Not sure if you've investigated that at all?)

Comment: CF https://ai.google.dev/available_regions#available_regions suggests it's based on the region the user is in (presumably this is the user whose account / API key is used to connect to the API)

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77659552/google-generative-ai-api-error-user-location-is-not-supported-for-the-api-use

Comment: Thank you for the list of available regions. Unfortunately, Germany is not on the list, where the server is located.
Is any workaround possible?

Comment: You'd need to host your application somewhere else. Or try a VPN - but if you're on a shared host that is unlikely to be an option

Comment: I don't recognize the SDK you are using. Edit your question and include a link. I am guessing it is this [one](https://github.com/gemini-api-php/client). That SDK uses the Gemini API which is not supported in Germany. You probably should switch to the Vertex AI (which does not support API Keys).